# Django WSGI application could not be loaded

Tags: django, python-3.x

I found an error while re-running the django application and there are some solutions on stackoverflow,but it is not working for me .

```
django.core.exceptions.ImproperlyConfigured: WSGI application
'myapp.wsgi.application' could not be loaded; Error importing module.
```

Also checked Django Middle-Ware,All are installed and Properly Configured.

Following are the Middle-Ware i am using

```
'django_session_timeout.middleware.SessionTimeoutMiddleware',
'django.middleware.common.CommonMiddleware',
'django.middleware.csrf.CsrfViewMiddleware',
'django.contrib.auth.middleware.AuthenticationMiddleware',
'django.contrib.messages.middleware.MessageMiddleware',
'django.middleware.clickjacking.XFrameOptionsMiddleware',
```

**MY DJANGO APPLICATION: myapp

WSGI_APPLICATION = 'myapp.wsgi.application'**

Django Version: 2.1.7
Python : 3.7.1

**WSGI.PY**

```
import os

from django.core.wsgi import get_wsgi_application

os.environ.setdefault('DJANGO_SETTINGS_MODULE', 'myapp.settings')

application = get_wsgi_application()
```

Comment: WSGI run config(eg. `.ini` or any **command**) and **run location** would be helpful to solve your problem. Can you attach it?

Comment: do you mean wsgi.py file?

Comment: import os

from django.core.wsgi import get_wsgi_application

os.environ.setdefault('DJANGO_SETTINGS_MODULE', 'myapp.settings')

application = get_wsgi_application()